# Java Date object problem

Tags: java

I'm doing a java program that will take an action based on the date and time.
the problem is that when I used the java.util.Date object i found that it is affected by the windows wall clock, i don't know what to do, I'm needing to the date to be never affected by anything, or if any one know how to take this action in another way
thank you very much

Comment: Can you post some codes and more concise example of the goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The system clock is where Java gets its time from--if you want a different time you'd need to use a time service on the internet. (Which also won't be unaffected "by anything", but it won't be affected by someone changing the system time.)

Comment: Post the code of what you have so far.  It will be easier to think that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a specific Date and Time you need to create an instance of `Date` with the date and time instance information you want instead of calling `new Date()` which will give you the `current` instance in time. Use the `GregorianCalendar` or some other `Calendar` sub-class.

If you want only the `Date` to be relevant you need to ZERO out the time ( hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds ) off your Date object.

```
public static Date setTime(final Date date, final int hourOfDay, final int minute, final int second, final int ms)
    {
        final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(date);
        gc.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        gc.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        gc.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
        gc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ms);
        return gc.getTime();
    }
```

then on your `Date` instance of `date` do `.setTime(date, 0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: But still, if someone changed the system clock (i.e. by changing the date in windows) this still would output a wrong date

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways ... You could set up a service somewhere on the web from which you grab a time. This way you make sure that all PCs you run this stuff on use the same time base.

Another way would be to use an NTP server... [Here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient) is an official release by the people who designed the NTP standard how you could use a Java Client to query an NTP server

Comment: I really thank you all,
but my program is Java Desktop Application and I'm not sure that the user will be connected to the internet, so i can't retrieve it from the internet.
also my program will take the date in the input time, saves it in a database and will take an action based on the saved Date. 
Like that i will not be apple to do the same input else after one day.

I may need to think out of box, any thing else date but i can't find any thing that gives me the same thing. if any one know another method, please send it.
thanks all

Comment: Well, if you need to rely on the system date you might need to invent some fancy checks. For example if `new Date()` represents a date that is earlier than **any** date in your database you know that the user has somehow tempered with their system clock... But that won't give you the real date just an info that something is not correct

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"never affected by anything"*, what exactly do you have in mind?

Since a user can (pretty much always) control their computer's internal clock, you will need to examine the date and time from an external source. Note that internal clocks often change with daylight saving hours too.

If you could use network time, or time from an internet server. NIST has such a service http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm. You should check out the network time protocol too.

But even this could **theoretically** be rerouted / changed by a devious person. So if you are after copy protection, or something security-related, you might need to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Date` class is getting the current time depending on the system clock. The system clock can be modified in multiple ways (the wall clock is one of those).

If you want the time without using the system clock, I recommend to try and fetch the time from Internet. Protocols such as NTP can do that. Some implementations exist in Java, see http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient.